# rundll32 equivalent for opening and viewing files in linux platforms

Tags: java, file

is there any equivalent for rundll32 in unix platforms through which we can view files???Also i want to know the code by which we can open and view the files(similar to a double click operation) by just passing the file location as a parameter.I managed to get it done in windows but in ubuntu i don't know how to get it implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) class , use `open()` method to open the file with default program